# ¿ Como hacer scroll infinito dividiendo el contenido en WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, scroll, seo

¿ Cual es la mejor manera de hacer scroll infinito y fraccionar el contenido de la pagina para que indexe mejor por Google?

Creando una tienda online queremos evitar al usuario el problema de tener que pasar pagina.

Entiendo que esta no es la mejor forma de hacer una pregunta, pero realmente no tenemos un ejemplo claro, y los que vi no se implementarlo
La opción ideal es el scroll infinito, que trae WordPress por defecto

**

### EDITO

**

El tema que estoy utilizando, he activado el scroll infinito, y me  pagina el contenido de la siguiente manera:
page/2/ , page/3/, page/4/, etc, etc...

El problema esta en que después de la segunda pagina page/4/, las imagenes de los productos no se muestran, es necesario recargar la pagina para que se muestren.

Esto es un lastre para cualquiera, más tratandose de una tienda

He leido algún articulo sobre la utilización de `AJAX` para conseguir esto, pero no se como implementarlo en mi sitio. y he leido muchas cosas en Medium, Google, etc.
Pero quizá no busque correctamente
¿ Donde puedo encontrar documentación para hacer esto ?

El problema viene para el `SEO` y los robots de Google que no interpretan bien mucho contenido.

He buscado información y [encontre documentación de Google](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2014/02/infinite-scroll-search-friendly) sobre esto,

Al parecer, existen dos funciones ( `replaceState` y `pushState` ) con las que se puede conseguir hacer un `scroll` infinito, y fragmentando el contenido

Pero realmente no se como implementarlo en WordPress

¿ Es necesario  `replaceState` y `pushState` para conseguir un scroll infinito con el contenido fragmentado ?

¿ Como puedo hacer un Scroll infinito fragmentando el contenido ?

EDITO DE NUEVO

He activado el scroll por defecto que tiene el tema que estoy utilizando, y si habilito Habilite la carga diferida para imágenes,  esta causando problemas, generando un espacio vacío dentro del contenedor de los producto.
Se puede ver en la imagen.

Añado los estilos de los productos para que se puedan ver, ya quizá el compañero @Arthur pueda darme alguna idea para corregir esto.

```html
<div
    class="product-small col has-hover product type-product post-278 status-publish first instock product_cat-nuestros-envasados product_cat-nuestros-envasados-sin-gluten product_tag-sin-gluten has-post-thumbnail purchasable product-type-simple">
    <div class="col-inner">

      <div class="badge-container absolute left top z-1">

      </div>
      <div class="product-small box ">
        <div class="box-image">
          <div class="image-none">
            <a href="" aria-label="Harina de trigo sarraceno 500 g">
              <img width="247" height="296" src="" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail"
                alt="harina de trigo sarraceno 500 gramos" decoding="async" loading="lazy"> </a>
          </div>
          <div class="image-tools is-small top right show-on-hover">
            <div class="wishlist-icon">
              <button class="wishlist-button button is-outline circle icon" aria-label="Wishlist">
                <i class="icon-heart"></i> </button>
              <div class="wishlist-popup dark">

                <div class="yith-wcwl-add-to-wishlist add-to-wishlist-278  wishlist-fragment on-first-load"
                  data-fragment-ref="278"
                  data-fragment-options="{&quot;base_url&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;in_default_wishlist&quot;:false,&quot;is_single&quot;:false,&quot;show_exists&quot;:false,&quot;product_id&quot;:&quot;278&quot;,&quot;parent_product_id&quot;:&quot;278&quot;,&quot;product_type&quot;:&quot;simple&quot;,&quot;show_view&quot;:false,&quot;browse_wishlist_text&quot;:&quot;Explorar la lista de deseos&quot;,&quot;already_in_wishslist_text&quot;:&quot;\u00a1El producto ya est\u00e1 en tu lista de deseos!&quot;,&quot;product_added_text&quot;:&quot;\u00a1Producto a\u00f1adido!&quot;,&quot;heading_icon&quot;:&quot;fa-heart-o&quot;,&quot;available_multi_wishlist&quot;:false,&quot;disable_wishlist&quot;:false,&quot;show_count&quot;:false,&quot;ajax_loading&quot;:false,&quot;loop_position&quot;:&quot;after_add_to_cart&quot;,&quot;item&quot;:&quot;add_to_wishlist&quot;}">

                  <!-- ADD TO WISHLIST -->

                  <div class="yith-wcwl-add-button">
                    <a href="?add_to_wishlist=278&amp;_wpnonce=1b6f9d6701"
                      class="add_to_wishlist single_add_to_wishlist" data-product-id="278" data-product-type="simple"
                      data-original-product-id="278" data-title="Añadir a la lista de deseos" rel="nofollow">
                      <i class="yith-wcwl-icon fa fa-heart-o"></i> <span>Añadir a la lista de deseos</span>
                    </a>
                  </div>

                  <!-- COUNT TEXT -->

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="image-tools is-small hide-for-small bottom left show-on-hover">
          </div>
          <div class="image-tools grid-tools text-center hide-for-small bottom hover-slide-in show-on-hover">
            <a class="quick-view quick-view-added" data-prod="278" href="#quick-view">Vista Rápida</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box-text box-text-products text-center grid-style-2" style="height: 245.781px;">
          <div class="title-wrapper">
            <p class="name product-title woocommerce-loop-product__title" style="height: 41.1797px;"><a href="/"
                class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">Harina de trigo sarraceno 500 g</a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="price-wrapper" style="height: 71.0703px;">
            <div class="pwb-brands-in-loop"><span><a href=""><img width="162" height="156" src=""
                    class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail" alt="" loading="lazy"></a></span><span><a href=""><img
                    width="242" height="258" src="" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail"
                    alt="certificado ecologico" loading="lazy"></a></span>
            </div>
            <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>4,03&nbsp;<span
                    class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span> P.V.P.</span>
            <p class="degradable">ENVASE RECICLABLE</p>
          </div>
          <form action="?add-to-cart=278" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="quantity buttons_added form-flat">
              <input type="button" value="-" class="minus button is-form"> <label class="screen-reader-text"
                for="quantity_642ab8820887b">Harina de trigo sarraceno 500 g cantidad</label>
              <input type="number" id="quantity_642ab8820887b" class="input-text qty text" name="quantity" value="1"
                title="Cantidad" size="4" min="0" max="" step="1" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric" autocomplete="off">
              <input type="button" value="+" class="plus button is-form">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="278"
              class="button alt ajax_add_to_cart               add_to_cart_button product_type_simple">COMPRAR</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Gracias

Comment: Eso es todo lo que tienes en tu functions?

Comment: Encontre varias formas de hacer el scroll, entre ellas esa función. Pero como debes saber, no es bueno el scroll infinito pata que los robots de Google indexen el contenido, es por ello que quiero encontrar la forma de mezclar la paginación con el scroll infinito, seccionar la pagina de la tienda en varias partes pero eliminando la paginación

Comment: Tienes una gran ventaja y es que lo que es relevante indexar son productos, no contenido de texto: quedas cubierto si tu sitemap.xml cubre todos los productos de tu tienda (asumiendo una página por producto). El límite es de 50.000 productos. Cuando alguien busque el producto en Google, encontrará el enlace directo a este en tu página.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, pero no entiendo muy bien que quieres decir, puedes aclararme un poco. El sitio puedo añadirlo Scroll infinito, lo tiene el tema por defecto, pero al paginar el contenido, las imagenes de los productos no se muestras después de la segunda pagina si no se recarga. Ahora me disponía a editar la pregunta. ¿ Puedes darme ideas?

Comment: Que tema estas usando?

Comment: Flatsome, y ya les pedi su opinion, pero como acabé el soporte hace tiempo, no responden. Es lamentable pero cierto, @JefferzonBol

Comment: Tienes en realidad 2 problemas, ambos relacionados con Infinite Scroll (IS): 1.SEO y 2. Imágenes que no cargan. El primero lo resuelves con un plugin que haga el sitemap de tu sitio (Googlebot utilizará este archivo para indexar toda tu página); el 2o puede estar relacionado con algún plugin que optimice las imágenes (como image optimizer de Jetpack), no trabajan bien con IS. Te recomendaría abandonar IS y seguir con la paginación tradicional, te ahorrarás tiempo y muchos problemas.

Comment: Vaya, seguire tus consejos. He corregido alguno de los problemas como el de la carga de imagenes, pero no me gusta como  funciona esto, no pagina muy bien

Comment: ¿Qué falos encuentras al paginar? (Por cierto, es la solución de los grandes portales, Google, Amazon, Ebay, etc.).

Comment: Ya, a Amazon ...., No cargan las imagenes de los productos, al subir de nuevo hacia arriba se queda trabado por ejemplo en la `page/3/`. Con el código que muestro en la pregunta, no funciona. Se estan comenzando a corregir alguno de los problemas. Ahora he comenzado a usar el scroll que tiene el tema y Creo que dejare como esta y seguire buscando un poco todos los dias. he habilitado la carga diferida de imagenes para satisfacer a search-console y veremos los resultados en los próximos dias

Comment: He leído en varias entradas sobre el problema del optimizador de imágenes con IS, en general no se entienden muy bien. El código de la pregunta se ve muy bien, creo que el problema es con la gestión de las imágenes; habría que ver cómo extenderlo para que una vez cargada la página actualice las imágenes... Cómo vas con el sitemap? Con este no tienes que preocuparte por el SEO, solo de resolver el problema de las imágenes.

Comment: Ayer empece con search-console. Como te dige, ahora todo parece funcionar bien. Elimine el código de la pregunta y unicamente esta el scroll que tiene el tema. Si habilito la carga diferida para imágenes, me produce problemas en el contenedor de los productos, por lo que lo [tengo deshabilitado](https://ibb.co/VNzrgPx). Puedes [ver el problema en la captura](https://ibb.co/Q8rH9XX)

Comment: Veo la captura pero no veo el problema, todas las imágenes aparecen. Otra opción sería crear un menú de cuántos productos mostrar por página; igual creo que solo los usuarios más expertos cambian "25 productos" por "100 productos".

Comment: Es el espacio que se muestra entre el titulo y el botón de añadir, es bastante molesto https://ibb.co/L134TWY

Comment: Ahora entiendo: podrías agregar un callback para reducir ese espacio, reposicionando los elementos una vez que se haya hecho la carga.

Comment: Creo que eso ya me supera un poco, gracias por tu sugerencia. Buscare información y ejemplos sobre esto de los callback. He estado leyendo y un callback es una función que se utiliza como argumento para potra función. Veré si puedo conseguir algo, por el momento he deshabilitado la carga diferida para imágenes. Gracias por tus consejos

Comment: Con gusto! Otra opción al callback es modificar la plantilla CSS, de tal manera que haya un máximo de altura en la ficha de la foto y precio. Si abres una nueva pregunta compartiendo el código css o javascript  podemos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: ¿ Donde puedo encontrar información sobre recargar las imagenes con callback ?

Comment: En el código que incluyes, el callback es la función `success`: Justo después de agregar el contenido (la función `$('.products').append(data);`) podría ir una que verifique que las imágenes cargaron, y si no, hacerlas recargar. Pero en la imagen de ejemplo, las imágenes están cargando, lo que quieres corregir es el espacio, y esto lo puedes hacer modificando el CSS, o agregando una línea a `success` para que lo ajuste. Habría que conocer el código CSS para ver cómo hacerlo.